# How do I loop through textboxes in Java?

Tags: java, loops, textbox

I have 10 textboxes named searchField1,searchField2...searchField10. How do I loop through them? Here's what I've got so far:

```
for(int i =1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    productListModel.addElement(FindProducts.addProducts(searchField+i.getText()));
}
```

Comment: What is a "textbox"? I can't guess if you are talking about AWT, Swing or some other API.

Comment: Yes, please give us more pertinent information to allow this question to be answerable including what GUI library you may be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this. You either have to use the java reflection API(which is too difficult and unpracticable for this) or store the textboxes in an array like this (assuming you mean the class JTextField with textbox):

```
JTextField[] searchField=new JTextField[10]
//... some code and functions 
for(int i =0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    nproductListModel.addElement(FindProducts.addProducts(searchField[i].getText()));
}
```

Note that the array is numbered from 0 to 9, not from 1 to 10! And don't forget to initialize every single JTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use so many fields, rather put them in array or list, then you can loop them through